# Group_By Persons and Return the Maximum Row Number

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, case, survival-analysis

I'm trying to set up data to run a survival model. The data is time-series. The columns of importance  are Name, `BeginningDateofStudy` and `DeathDate`. What I would like to do is use a CASE statement where if the person is dead then only their last row is given a value of 1.

**For example**, if person A has a `BeginningDateofStudy = 01/07/2019` and their `DeathDate = 01/08/2020`, then they will have 12 rows of data (1 for each month) and only the new column created will report only the 12th row equaling  1, the others leading up to 12 will equal 0.

I'm actually pretty stumped on how to approach this. So far, I've attempted to return the max row number by name but I haven't had luck on that either. The best of my attempted tries is probably:

`MAX(row_number()) over(partition by name order by name, processdate desc) as MaxRow`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help -- an an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data / desired results I can only assume you are trying to do something like this. I use the CASE statement to check for max processdate and deathdate and assign 1's and zero's accordingly. If this isnt what youre after then you should supply the requested data/output/

```
SELECT 
    Name
    , BeginningDateofStudy
    , DeathDate
    , 
        CASE 
            WHEN DeathDate IS NOT NULL AND ProcessDate=(SELECT MAX(ProcessDate) FROM SurvivalMode WHERE Name=s.Name) THEN 1
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DeathDate) FROM SurvivalModel WHERE Name=s.Name)>0 THEN 0
            END AS DeadValue
FROM
    SurvivalModel s
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, assuming the process date does not go past the death date:

```
SELECT 
    Name
    , BeginningDateofStudy
    , DeathDate
    , CASE 
            WHEN DeathDate IS NOT NULL AND MONTH(Processdate)=MONTH(Deathdate) and YEAR(Processdate)=Year(Deathdate) then 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS DeadValue
FROM
    SurvivalModel s
```

However, this method would fail if the process date goes above the month of death date.